# Use older VS Extensions with VS-2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

How does Visual Studio identifies, a particular VS Extension should be installed for which version.

I am trying to use an older extension with VS-2013 at my own risk. As `.VSIX` internally is just a zip file I should be able to tweak version info in definition file.

Any pointers in this direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All supported VS versions are listed in the .vsixmanifest file inside the "zip" file. There are v1 (VS 2010+) and v2 (VS 2012+) slightly different schemes of this file. In v2 look for "Version Range" and in v1 look for "SupportedProducts".