# "Visual Studio" "Extensions and Updates" compatibility between versions & years. Is it safe to tell VS to install it anyway?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compatibility

**Q:** Modifying a VSIX file to declare it compatible with Visual Studio Comunity 2015. Is this a good idea, and if so, how can I do this?

---

**More information, a specific example:**

I'm trying to add either of the following to Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 8.1:

For VS 2010: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ba57efa3-4061-4cdf-97f5-51715c4f120a

For VS 2012 & 2013: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b61cc443-4790-42b7-b7ab-2691119667d2

The file provided opens with "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector".

---

**Specific example continued, Installation Failed:**

I'm then presented with an "Installation Failed" message and a log file, these are the important parts:

```
Name: SharpGL
...
Supported Products:
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCSExpress
...
```

This **does not seem to include my product**, but then:

```
Searching for applicable products...
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
Found installed product - Global Location
```

Great, **I have a compatible product**! However:

```
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException:
    This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
    at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
    at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Confusing!

VS Community appears to have replaced and be very similar to VS Express. Today trying to download VS Express from the Microsoft website yields only VS Community.

Comment: Uhm, this has nothing to do with VS-Community or not. The linked VSIX is just for VS **2010**

Comment: Good point, and there is a 2012, 2013 one too, question adapted, partly as it's the same problem, can I just manually adjust the vertion number it claims to support? I certainly don't want to run old vertions of VS as well. And partly because it has never-the-less found a compatible product, but then gets stuck.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269980/how-to-install-manually-vsix-2011-in-visual-studio-2012 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829652/use-older-vs-extensions-with-vs-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Community Edition was released as a replacement for VS Express Editions.
Express editions don't support Extensions / Plugins.

for VXIS packages the version of VS supported is decided by the package itself when you execute it to install (it's basically msi installation package that gives you a list of supported versions)

Usually the supported versions is in the manifest inside the package, getting support in for a different version I believe requires a fresh compile.

In other words ...

If you want to install a VSIX extension in to a particular version of VS you need the version of the VSIX that matches that version of VS

Comment: So nothing I can do as this doesn't exist, ok.

Comment: possibly ... hard to say without a more specific question about the package and the VS version you want to get working together

Comment: I have little more information. I've given lots of information in the question, your answer seems quite clear, I'm trying to avoid complexity here as the tool should be hard enough if it works properly, your saying it's not a good idea to try and fix the files myself.

Comment: The first statement is not true. Express edition still permits commercial usage while Community edition is not. So it is more of a complement.